# Submanifold shortest distance points orthogonal to Tangent space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a submanifold and $p\in R^n\setminus M, n \in N$ and $d(x,y) = \lVert x-y\lVert_2$, $x,y\in R^n$.

Show that if $q\in M$ is the point with the shortest distance from p $=>d(p,q)<=d(y,q) \forall y \in M$ then $p-q$ is orthogonal to the Tangent space of M in p with the standard euclidean scalar product $=>\langle p-q, y\rangle = 0$ $\forall y\in T_bM$

I have come to the point where i can estimate that $\langle p-q, y\rangle <=\lVert p\lVert_2\lVert y\lVert_2-\lVert q\lVert_2\lVert y\lVert_2 $ but i don't know i am on the right path or i went into a completely wrong direction.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, there exists for any element $v\in T_qM$ a smooth curve $c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ with $c(0)=q$ and $c'(0)=v$. Now we define the function

\begin{equation}
f(t):=||c(t)-p||^2.
\end{equation}

Since $q=c(0)$ is the point on the submanifold with minimal distance to $p$ and the curve $c$ lies entirely in $M$, we conclude that the function $f$ has a local minimum at $t=0$. Therefore, we get
\begin{align}
0=f'(0)&=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\langle c(t)-p,c(t)-p\rangle\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} \bigg(\langle c(t),c(t)\rangle -2\langle c(t),p\rangle+\langle p,p\rangle\bigg)\\
&=2\langle \dot{c}(0),c(0)\rangle-2\langle \dot{c}(0),p\rangle\\
&=2\langle v,q-p\rangle
\end{align}

which is precisely what we had to show.

If it's not clear to you how I differentiated the inner products, I suggest writing down the expressions explicitly in coordinates.